# How to avoid removing entity from many to many in jpa

Tags: java, jpa, many-to-many, cascade

I have this mapping at Person entity:

```
@ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinTable(name = "PersonAddress", joinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "personId") }, inverseJoinColumns = {
        @JoinColumn(name = "addressId") })
private Set<Address> addresses;
```

And this at Address entity:

```
@ManyToMany(mappedBy = "addresses")
private Set<Person> owners;
```

I tried all cascade options available, but everytime when I save a Person entity it removes all relations with addresses. Is it possible to keep addresses when saving Person?

Answer (score 0):

its not recommended to use CascadeType.REMOVE or CascadeType.ALL in to-many associations, you should  implement the removal of child entities yourself.
Here the link it explains with details how to do the implementation.

https://thorben-janssen.com/avoid-cascadetype-delete-many-assocations/

Comment: As you can see I'm not using any cascade option at the moment, and I want to AVOID the deletion.